# NSThread is failing to load Selector method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsthread

So, I am trying to connect to a remote server to get and show data. in `viewDidLoad` I use an `NSThread` to call a function called `doSomething`

```
- (void)doSomething
{        
    @autoreleasepool
    {                
        NSMutableURLRequest *httpRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:someURL];
        [httpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [httpRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", httpRequestParametersClean.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [httpRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [httpRequest setHTTPBody:httpRequestParametersClean];

        (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:httpRequest delegate:self];

        for (NSString* key in response)
        {
             // loop through returned values
        }
     }
}
```

The code in `viewDidLoad` is

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(someURL) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then I have a `REFRESH` button which when clicked calls `doSomething` as well
by simply saying `[self doSomething]`

My problem is that when view is loaded, the response from server comes empty. I still get no response until I click on the refresh button. Strange! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can see that NSThread is calling getTableViewCells instead of doSomething

Comment: this a typo. The problem still exist even when I am sure that the thread is calling the right function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NSURLConnection` created with `initWithRequest:delegate:` works *asynchronously*, calling the delegate functions `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, `connection:didReceiveData:`, ... later, when data is read from the server. Your code does not even `start` the connection, so nothing will happen anyway.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to use the synchronous version

```
sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

of `NSURLConnection`. If `doSomething` is executed in a separate thread, this will not block the UI.

*Added:* (Thanks to @geowar for mentioning this.) Note that you can also use the delegate-based `NSURLConnection` methods. These are more flexible (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591636/1187415 for a comparison). Another good choice is `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, which creates a background thread automatically.

Comment: doesn't (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:httpRequest delegate:self]; start the connection?

Comment: `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` and `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:YES` start the connection immediately, but not `initWithRequest:delegate:`.

Comment: While this is the correct answer to the question asked, a better solution would be to use the asynchronous method and the delegate callback methods.

Comment: @geowar: The asynchronous method is more flexible, but if you don't need these advantages then the synchronous method on a background thread works as well. There is also `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, which saves you from creating a thread.

Comment: @geowar: Thank you for your feedback, I have added your and my comments to the answer.